# Getting system model name using C++ on AIX

Tags: c++, aix

I need to (via a C++ program) get the system model name. Platform is AIX 5.3. Basically I need to get the same information as "uname -M" command. e.g. IBM, 1234-E4A

I tried using the uname() but could not get this information.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you don't appear to be getting this information with `uname`. What is the content of the `machine` field in the `utsname` structure when you call `uname`? That's where it should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
int main (void) {
    struct utsname uts;
    if (uname (&uts) == -1)
        printf ("Error, errno = %d\n", errno);
    else
        printf ("%s\n", uts.machine);
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, based on the doco from IBM, they treat `machine` slightly differently.

> `subroutine uname utsname.machine`: 32-bit unique system identifier represented as a hexadecimal character string, such as "0123454C".

So that's the system ID rather than a machine type.

---

As a last resort, you can always do the kludgy `system ("uname -M >/tmp/myfile");`
and then read in `myfile` with the standard C I/O stuff.

However, though that may be necessary is standard C, we can do better in AIX, since we have `popen` available to us. This allows us to run the command and examine its output *without* the hassle of creating and reading a temporary file.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch;
    FILE *fin = popen ("uname -M", "r");
    if (fin != NULL) {
        while ((ch = fgetc (fin)) != EOF) {
            putchar (ch);
        }
        fclose (fin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Augh.  Use popen for crying out loud.

Comment: @Charlie, perhaps you should read the _whole_ answer before commenting :-) But I'll de-emphasize the tempfile bit.

Comment: .machine gives me something like this  machine = '000682C2D900';

Comment: @ababeel, I suspect not. However, I'd be using the popen rather than system one.